# MongoDB doc saves, but following function won't fire

Tags: node.js, mongodb

The following snippet of code will save the document to the database, however it will not throw an error or the socket1 emit.  The socket2 emit will work however.  What is the error in this query?

```
    db.doc.findOne({field1: value1}, function(err, doc) {
        if (!doc) {
            db.doc.save({field1: value1, field2: value2, field3: value3}, function(err, saved) {
                if( err || !saved ) console.log("User not saved");
                else socket.emit('socket1', value1, value2);                    
            });                     
        }
        else {
            socket.emit('socket2', value1);             
        }
    });
```

Comment: does this use `mongoose` or `node-mongodb-native`?

Comment: I am using MongoJS for this app.

Comment: I have never heard of MongoJS. What does your `require("...")` call look like? If you type `npm list`, do you see `mongoose` or `node-mongodb-native` installed?

Answer (score 0):

You may try `save({...}, {safe:true}, function(...) {...})`

Comment: Thanks, this worked. Also helps to deploy away from localhost :P